# Не могу залить Android приложение в Play Market

Tags: android, google-play

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Всем привет! 
Пытаюсь залить своё приложение в маркет и ничего не получается.
Заливаю .aab файл
Он загружается на сервер и начинается бесконечный processing... как видно на скрине.
Пробовал уже два приложения с разных аккаунтов и компьютеров.
Может быть у кого-то было и кто-то знает решение?

Comment: а как вы генерируете данный файл?

Comment: Через Android Studio

Comment: это понятно, опишите по пунктам что именно вы делаете

Comment: Выбираю создать Android App Bundle, создаю ключ подписи, ввожу пароль от ключа, возраст и имя, нажимаю дальше, выбираю релиз, всё. Беру готовый файл из папки.

Comment: используйте generate signed apk и там выбирайте app bundle